# "Mark as read" functionality in Plone 4.1.4

Tags: plone, iso

Using Plone as a Document Management System for a Quality Management Program (capitalized buzzwords for added effect...), we are looking for "Reading list" functionality.

This should provide two functions:

- Show the end-users which new documents have been updated that they haven't read yet
- Show the Quality manager who hasn't read certain updated documents

Added thoughts, preferably the status of the document in the workflow should stay the same (we thought about adding a "pending reading"-state but decided against it).

Together with some of my previous questions answered here of Stackoverflow, we would then be just about ready to roll out what seems to be a ISO9001-compliant document management system, in Plone, open-source, practically all through the web - I can't say I expected this three weeks ago...

Does anybody know of such a product?

Comment: You should get in touch with FourDigits, they already implemented ISO certification using Plone: http://blog.fourdigits.nl/iso-9001-2008-certification-using-plone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can only be done with a custom product.

The way I would do this is by registering a viewlet (or a portlet) associated with the content-type of the document, providing a button.

The button, when clicked, will write the user-id and the content-id somewhere, perhaps in an annotation or in an external database (Redis, MySQL). Additional views, viewlets, and portlets will be needed to provide information to End-users and Managers about what has been read or not.

Comment: Looks like we've got our work cut out for us... Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It isn't trivial, but neither too complicated to implement. 

Feel free to visit Plone's official IRC channel on Freenode: irc://irc.freenode.net/plone for additional pointers and tips on how to get it done.